# Visual Studio subscription with Action Pack

Tags: visual-studio

I have an Action Pack subscription. According to the partner website, I should get 3 Visual Studio 2015 professional licenses. 
However, I cannot find the subscriptions tab or activation link anywhere.
Can someone give some help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Professional with Microsoft Action Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060668/visual-studio-professional-with-microsoft-action-pack)

Answer (score -1):

Following the steps provided in **[this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2954371)** kb article worked for me:

Step one 
In the microsoft partner portal, note your Individual user's First Name, Last Name, Email address, and technical ID. You can find this under 
*Administration -> Your individual account page -> Privileges tab*

Step two
Activate the subscription **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/add/default.aspx)** 
 
If step two did not work, first verify that the user you wish to give a subscription is assigned a Technical Contact role for the organization.  You'll see this under the 
*'Requirements & Assets'-> Assign Contact Roles menu option*.

Lastly, use the same account at the login prompt when you open visual studio to retrieve a valid license.

Comment: Link under Step two is out of date